# Why my website subpage displays "www.domainname.com/#!home/" why "/#!"

Tags: web-development, ajax

i am taking over a webpage from a previous webpage designer, and i am wondering why does the website display "#!"? eg. www.domainname.com/**#!**home/mainPage.  How do I change this so that it doesn't display?

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by pages loaded with javascript/ajax.

There are a few articles online that can help you:

1. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started
2. http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs/
3. http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/

Answer (score 0):

Search your files for `location.hash` you'll probably find it in either a JavaScript or jQuery function